# count(*) and having not selecting for same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a small doubt on regards how to organize a group_by.

I have this report that lists different we_date for each employee_payroll.  one employee payroll can have records on multiple we_dates.

I want to select only when an employee_payroll has more than 4 occurences (disregarding the date column)

I understand that I need to do it either with a having count(employee_payroll) > 4 or a sub-query,
however when I try to do the having it asks me to group by using the date column, and this doesn't return the count per employee_payroll I need. (If I add a count(employee_payroll) I receive 1 in all rows, but I cannot not group by the date field. what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Include sample data, expected results and the query you have tried please

Comment: *"I understand that I need to do it either with a having count(employee_payroll) > 4 or a sub-query, however when I try to do the having it asks me to group by using the date column"* Because you, presumably, have the column `Timesheet_We_Date` in your `SELECT`, but it is neither in your `GROUP BY` nor aggregated. Actually post your attempt(s) so we can explain where you went wrong and what you need to do to correct it.

Comment: yes Larnu, you're correct, but I didn't want to group by the date, (as it will give me unique results)  it is isn't that I'm getting an error but more than I'm not sure how to approach it, the solution below from Ven seems to tackle what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to select only when an employee_payroll has more than 4 occurences (disregarding the date column)

You would use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, count(*) over (partition by employee_payroll) as cnt
      from employee e
     ) e
where cnt >= 4;
```

Explicit aggregation is probably not the best way to return this result.

Comment: THIS!  yes, I always try to use windows functions when presented with this type of situations, however when it applies I didn't catch it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to tell without the actual error you are getting that asks you to group by we_date, but in theory this should be what you have to do:

```sql
SELECT employee_payroll
FROM table
GROUP BY employee_payroll
HAVING count(employee_payroll) > 4;
```

Comment: This doesn't feel right; it's just going to return a bunch of `int` values, with a value greater than `4`, with no meaning with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get employees with > 4 occurances. Then , only select those employee rows.

```sql
;WITH CTE_EmployeeWithGreaterThanFourOccurance (
    SELECT Employee_Payroll, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY Employee_Payroll
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
)
SELECT *
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN CTE_EmployeeWithGreaterThanFourOccurance AS c
    ON c.Employee_Payroll = e.Employee_Payroll
```